# Non-integer Arguments for R's phyper Function

Tags: r, distributions, hypergeometric-distribution

In the code below, why does phyper return a result for non-integer arguments? I would expect it to complain bitterly in the same fashion dhyper did.

```
> dhyper(x=7,m=10,n=1000-10,k=400)
[1] 0.04193348
> phyper(q=7,m=10,n=1000-10,k=400)
[1] 0.9880648

> dhyper(x=7,m=10.5,n=1000-10.5,k=400)
[1] NaN
Warning message:
In dhyper(x = 7, m = 10.5, n = 1000 - 10.5, k = 400) : NaNs produced
> phyper(q=7,m=10.5,n=1000-10.5,k=400)
[1] 0.9716014
```

Comment: Possibly something to do with these: 
`phyper(q=6.99999989999999,m=10.5,n=1000-10.5,k=400)` and  
`phyper(q=6.99999990000000,m=10.5,n=1000-10.5,k=400)`

Comment: Wow. As far as I know neither function should take non-integer arguments. Is there something beyond what I know that makes this reasonable behavior?

Comment: (+1) The `dhyper` behavior could be considered a bug.  `phyper` is acting just fine, so you can use it to work around the bug, as in `phyper(7,10.5,1000-10.5,400) - phyper(6,10.5,1000-10.5,400)`. The reason why this could be considered OK concerns what "the" Hypergeometric distribution is and therefore its discussion is on-topic here.

Comment: @whuber -- can you suggest a reference that discusses non-integer arguments in the hypergeometric distribution?

Comment: You could just use the identity relating the factorial and  gamma functions to construct a real-valued hypergeometric distribution function.

Comment: I understand that it is mathematically possible, but what is the model that gives rise to such a distribution? What does it mean to have 10.5 marbles? I have never seen this discussed before, so that is what I would like to learn more about.

Comment: There doesn't necessarily have to be any such model.  It suffices that extending the definition to comprise non-integral parameters produces a potentially useful and flexible family of distributions. Exactly the same thing has been done with the Beta, F, Student t, and many other distributions that originated with integral parameter values but now include real parameter values. For more on such generalizations and their uses, see Johnson & Kotz, *Univariate Discrete Distributions.*

Comment: Thanks everyone. All of my remaining questions are software specific and are probably best directed toward the folks at the R Foundation.